# Length cannot be negative (Exception)

Tags: c#

i have been doing an exercise on codeeval:
https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/30/submit/?lid=1335504

here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(args[0]))
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            string b = "";
            string c = "";
            string[] b2;
            string[] c2;
            int x = 0;
            string line = reader.ReadLine();
            if (null == line)
                continue;
            // do something with line
            else{
            x = line.IndexOf(";");
            b = line.Substring(x +1);
            b2 = b.Split(',');
            c = line.Substring(0, (line.Length - ((b.Length) + 1)));
            c2 = c.Split(',');
            foreach (string u in b2) {
                    foreach (string i in c2)
                    {
                        if (int.Parse(u) == int.Parse(i))
                        {
                            result.Append(u + ",");
                        }
                    }
                }
            Console.WriteLine(result.ToString().Substring(0, result.Length - 1));
            result.Clear();
            Array.Clear(b2, 0 , b2.Length);
            Array.Clear(c2, 0 , c2.Length);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When i run on my VS, it works on 1 string. However, it run one or two lines then gives me an exeception when i run it on codeeval. I don't know why the length can be negative...???

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Cannot be
>   negative. Parameter name: length   at System.String.Substring (Int32
>   startIndex, Int32 length) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   Cannot be negative. Parameter name: length   at
>   System.String.Substring (Int32 startIndex, Int32 length) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Program.Main (System.String[] args)
>   [0x00000] in :0

the input are

```
68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82;78,79,80,81,82,83,84
87,88,89,90,91,92,93;64,65,66,67,68
87,88,89,90,91,92;81,82,83,84,85,86,87
82,83,84,85,86;68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80
78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91;67,68,69,70,71,72
```

Comment: edit link: https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/30/

Comment: Either `(line.Length - ((b.Length) + 1))` is returning a negative number. You need to work out why `b` is longer than `line` or `result.Length - 1` is returning a negative number (i.e. `result` is an empty string).

Comment: Use debug and see what happend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`result` will be blank if  `if (int.Parse(u) == int.Parse(i))` is false for all iterations. So that you will get `result=""` and up on extracting sub-string `result.Length - 1` will point to a negative index. which is not valid.

```
.Substring(0, result.Length - 1)// points to a negative index which is invalid.
```

You can avoid such error by checking result value before processing with it. ie.,

```
if(result.ToString()!="")
{
  //Process your code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = line.IndexOf(";");
b = line.Substring(x +1);
b2 = b.Split(',');
c = line.Substring(0, (line.Length - ((b.Length) + 1)));
```

- Your input does not contain a `";"`
- So `x = -1` and `b = line` (so `line.Length = b.Length`)
- `line.Length - ((b.Length) + 1) = -1`

So you call `Substring` with a length of `-1`.

**[UPDATE]** Oops, just realized there *are* `;` in your input. Anyway, my example still leads to the same exception if you don't verify your input. So I won't delete this answer as it still makes a point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this line:

```
c = line.Substring(0, (line.Length - ((b.Length) + 1)));
```

If `line` does not contain a `;` then:

1. `x = line.IndexOf(";");` will set `x` to -1.
2. `b = line.Substring(x +1);` will result in `b == line`.
3. `line.Length - ((b.Length) + 1)` will result in a negative number.

There are other failure modes too, I imagine.